# Obtener el siguiente elemento dentro del ciclo for

Tags: python

Quisiera en el else poder acceder al siguiente valor de la tupla, para factorizar un numero.

```py
def factor_num(num:int) -> tuple:
    """
    Esta función retorna una tupla con la factorizacion del numero que se le pase como parametro
    """
    
    factores = []
    prim_fact = (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97)
    
    for div in prim_fact:
        while True:
            if es_primo(num) :
                factores.append(num)
                break            
            elif num % div == 0:                                                        
                factores.append(div)
                num//=div                                                
            else:
                div = prim_fact[+1] <= aca!!
                
                                             
        return tuple(factores)
```

Comment: ¿Qué esperas devolver en la única tupla que regresaría esta función? Lo pregunto porque más creo que quieres devolver una lista de tuplas, pero veamos cuál es tu diseño primero.

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro si entendí pero creo que esta puede ser una solución

```
def factor_num(num: int) -> tuple:
    factores = []
    prim_fact = (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97)

    for index, div in enumerate(prim_fact):
        while True:
            if es_primo(num):
                factores.append(num)
                break
            elif num % div == 0:
                factores.append(div)
                num //= div
            else:
                next_index = index + 1
                if next_index < len(prim_fact):
                    div = prim_fact[next_index]
                else:
                    # No hay más valores en la tupla prim_fact
                    break

    return tuple(factores)
```